# Using Java exec to Run a jar from JSP with JRI

Tags: java, jsp, jri

I got a task to run R script in java, so I used the JRI library for this case, and I need call it from jsp, so I write a page simply call by

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -Djava.library.path=/home/XXX/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/rJava/jri/ -cp /home/XXX/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/rJava/jri -jar /home/XXX/MyJar.jar")
```

This method -> re.waitForR() always return false

```
Rengine re = new Rengine(new String[] { "--vanilla" }, false, null);
if (!re.waitForR()) {
    System.out.println("Cannot load R");
    return;
}
```

But when I run with console

```
java -Djava.library.path=/home/XXX/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/rJava/jri/ -cp /home/XXX/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/rJava/jri -jar /home/XXX/MyJar.jar
```

It is good and no error happened!

How can I do?

PS. My Jsp runs on Jetty.